# Why is the Big Bang the biggest explosion in the universe?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, popular-science

1. What makes the [big bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) the biggest explosion in the universe?
2. Why even should such an explosion ever happens?
3. Through what process and how does this amount of energy get released as a big bang?
4. Are there there behind the darkness of universe more big bangs?
5. If there are how could we ever know (since the speed of light is constant)?

Comment: firstly, I think Hawking's book will be able to answer those questions.
second, the big bang is supposed to be the "thing" that created the universe. So, thats why it "should" happen.

Comment: It's better to ask a single question at a time, rather than packing a list of questions into one. Your question about energy is answered here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/ . The misconception about the Big Bang as an explosion in a preexisting space is addressed here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591/

Comment: +0-1. The big bang isn't an explosion and the post is too jumbled and unclear for anyone to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The big bang is not an explosion in the conventional sense of the word. The big bang corresponds to an exponential expansion of spacetime and it is this incredible rate of expansion that can be dubbed "explosive".

There are [people suggesting that there might be "more universes"](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/421999/astronomers-find-first-evidence-of-other-universes/) and that we can detect their effect in the [CMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background_radiation). I remember however that recent [Planck data seemed to rule out the circles they found as statistical noise](http://coraifeartaigh.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/planck-and-the-inflationary-universe/).

Comment: The big bang wasn't necessarily an "exponential expansion," unless you assume inflation. I also don't think it makes sense to talk about an "incredible rate of expansion." How would you measure this rate, and what would you compare it against to show that it was big? If you measure it as $\dot{a}/a$, then it's not necessarily true that it was bigger at early times than at later times -- it depends on the equation of state.