# About a *center of the universe*

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

I understand that the history of our universe began with an explosion - the Big Bang. Now, I saw a comment in some old post, that "the universe has no center". Is that true? If there was initially a point, then all the galaxies have to fly away of that point. It seems to me that if we choose some arbitrary center of the universe, then, in the direction opposite to the true center we'll see less galaxies than in the direction of the true center.

Also, it seems to me that in the direction opposite to the center we'll see that the far galaxies are older, while in the direction toward the center the far galaxies will look younger.

Am I right? Is there a center of the universe? Also, is there such a concept as *age* of a galaxy?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591/

Comment: @dmckee I don't argue with you, but I would appreciate if you can indicate where I can see answers to my questions about ages of galaxies (if there is such a thing) and if is, do we see indeed such an anisotropy of ages?

Comment: @dmckee if you say that it's a duplicate I can close the question by myself, but are there answers to the issues of age and anisotropy? I'd like to see these things. So, I wait for your answer.

Comment: Galaxies do have ages (i.e. time since they formed) and while many formed at roughly the same early epoch others have been forming since. None-the-less we see galaxies from the Earliest birth cohort in all directions, and of course we see them younger when they are farther away.

Comment: @dmckee then, is the center of the universe - the place where the Big Bang occurred, close to the Milky way?

Comment: The big bang occurred *everywhere*. There is no "center". Space did not come out from a place, it was all there and it *all* grew bigger. This is the answer to the earlier versions of this question, too.

Comment: @dmckee I understand what you say but I seem to disagree. Imagining a point source emitting a spherical wave, in the beginning the sphere is a point, the point of the Big Bang, but as the radius of the wave increases the sphere expands - our universe expands. Though, the wave has a center. Where is the difference between the two cases?