# Backtracking position

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

Using a hypothetical photo from a hypothetical telescope, we were able to determine that the farthest galaxy present in the photo is 1 billion light years away. Because we are awesome we were able to also tell which direction all the galaxies in the pic are moving. We are also capable to estimate the mass of the galaxies.

In possession of these information aren't we capable to locate their "source", aka the local of the big bang? In another words, can we, in possession of objects current position, mass and relative speed tell where they were?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: @Vaimsus my question is not that. My question is: in possession of position, speed and mass of objects can we trace them back in time? ill edit the question to clarify...

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Leonardo. The duplicate that Vaimsus suggests expalins that there is no source of all the galaxies and the Big Bang didn't have a location. The anser to *Did the Big Bang happen at a point?* is **no**. To some extent we can trace galaxy motions back in time, though it's harder than you think because galaxies orbit each other in chaotic ways and even collide. Anyhow, if we did trace their paths back they'd all meet right here in my living room. But then, any alien observer anywhere in the universe would find exactly the same thing (assuming aliens have living rooms).