# Direction of travel in universe

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

When observe the universe we see that galaxies are much closer than they are at this very moment because of the time it takes for the light to reach us.

However do we see this phenomenon in every direction we look, or is one side observed as denser than the other, because that is where the big bang took place?

Comment: No, there is no centre of the universe. Related: [Does the universe have a center?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/does-the-universe-have-a-center)

Comment: The big bang took place right here, where you are. More precisely, it is still taking place.

Comment: The universe, on large scales, looks the same in every direction, and is homogeneous.  That, of itself, is very important and along with its expansion in all directions led to the standard cosmology equations which have been verified by very accurate measurements. It also led to the theory of inflation needed to make it all consistent. Read more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute location, absolute direction, and absolute time are in-explainable with current physics. Therefore absolute speed/velocity does not make sense either. The absolute point where all the expanded matter was concentrated at/before the big bang, may pertain to some location within universe. Even if the point itself expanded, the original reference still has to be within three dimensions, somewhere.

At the time, we can only comprehend the relative location, direction, and time.  And, considering relativity, the big bang seems to have taken place everywhere, all the time, in all directions.

Comment: Strictly speaking, absolute location is about as inexplainable in physics as the tooth fairy... because neither are necessary. Curiously, this seems to have been known since at least Newton's time, and it seems to have given almost everybody since some tooth aches, too, which is probably the result of a curiously human tendency to want the absolute, no matter at what cost. :-)