# Is there something like a fixed absolute position in space

Tags: space

Imagine a spacecraft floating around and everything else in the universe gone. Could the people on the spacecraft figure out if they are sitting in one place or are moving in the nothingness without any reference point to use for measurements?

Comment: No. This is the whole point of special relativity.

Comment: You're thought experiment has been very well studied already, it's called Minkowski spacetime https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space

Comment: Related to [Does the universe have a center ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/does-the-universe-have-a-center)

Comment: @AaronStevens, why not post this as an answer and earn you some points?

Comment: @nielsnielsen I'm not free enough to currently write out a good answer. I wouldn't be upset if you or any one else went ahead and did it.

Answer (score 3):

No. This dates back to Galileo. All frames of reference are equally valid, and there is no preferred "rest" frame.