# Is universe symmetric about a point?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, symmetry, universe, space-expansion

We have a good amount of discussion and theories on the formation of universe.

I want to ask is universe symmetric about a point?
I think that the answer should depend upon the uniformity of expansion of universe in several directions! Am I correct or completely wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591/2451 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s even stronger than that. There is good evidence to suggest that, at very large scales, the universe is very nearly isotopic and homogeneous about *every* point. Most notably, the cosmic microwave background is almost perfectly spherically symmetric, with relative temperature fluctuations on the order of $10^{-5}$.

I think the idea that the universe would be spherically symmetric about a single point comes from a common misconception that the expansion of the universe (the “Big Bang”) started at a single point like an explosion. However, this isn’t how our current understanding of the universe works at all. Instead, cosmological models suggest that the Big Bang happened everywhere, all at once. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4c-gX9MT1Q&vl=en) is a very nice MinutePhysics video about the topic.

Comment: The elementary level video that you've linked equally applies to the Milne universe that is expanding as an explosion that has started at a very particular point in space.