# Is the location of everything relative?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

I have heard that everything in our physical reality is relative. But I wonder:

- Does the universe have an edge? In an expanding sphere, there would be an edge is it like that?
- If the above is true then isn't everything relative to the edge. And not relative to eachother? Also, the speed of an object could be measured not as its speed moving away from an object but rather its speed moving away from the edge when it started or at all times (there would be a cancelation and I guess that would mean it could even be a - speed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the universe have a center?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591/)

Comment: Everything is *not* relative, and the universe does *not* have an edge. Some things that are *absolute*: the speed of light; the invariant mass of any system; the spacetime interval between two events. The universe is more like the *surface* of the expanding balloon (except in one higher dimension) than the *interior* of the balloon.

Comment: The speed of light has been shown to be changing.

Comment: @PaulChilds Please provide a reputable reference. As far as I am aware, that is non-mainstream physics. Also, even if it were true, *changing* is not the same as *relative*.

Comment: Someone with no references asking for references... http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/~mmurphy/research/are-natures-laws-really-universal/

Comment: But absolute is not the same as changing.