# Can the coordinate of the big bang point be calculated via observed universe or it is impossible?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, observable-universe

We know all galaxies spread out after [Big Bang theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang).The key idea is that the universe is expanding after that theory.  Can we play back the scenes via observable universe (galaxies) and can we calculate the coordinate of big bang point as a fixed reference point in  the universe?

Is there a such calculation in literature or claim?

EDIT: After answers I have some questions:

If the distribution of matter in the universe is homogeneous,how should we think the geometry of universe. Is it a sphere ? Does not a line go to endless as we imagine?  Is there any idea of the border of observed universe? If the universe is homogeneous and like sphere geometry, can we see the beginning of our baby galaxy while observing in the sky?

I really will  appreciate if someone explains what the  universe geometry structure is if we have a homogeneous universe after big bang.

Thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=71

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591/2451 and links therein.

Comment: And a *really* cool example to illustrate that: http://www.exploratorium.edu/hubble/tools/center.html

Comment: Big Bang happened 'everywhere', no matter where you will stand you will be center of the universe, its called [Cosmological Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle)

Comment: If you have an expanding balloon, can you tell where on the surface of the balloon the expansion started? (there's no such thing, actually)

Comment: If we were to use space-time coordinates (x,y,z,t)  could we pinpoint it at (0,0,0,0)

Comment: If the Universe is like the surface of a sphere, and if we ignore accelerated expansion due to Dark Energy, then one day we might see our galaxy "younger". However the Universe may be infinte in size (and yes the bigbang happened everywhere). If the Universe is like a sphere and  we consider the effect of Dark Energy, and, as far as we know, it will let our Universe expands so fast that our light will never be able to do return to us.

Comment: @mikhailcazi That diagram is the best I've ever seen to explain simply why everywhere seems to be the centre

Answer (score 15):

It is not possible to calculate the coordinates of the point where the Big Bang happened, because there is no such point. All of space is expanding away from the rest of space, in a manner that looks the same throughout space (the technical term is that the universe is homogeneous). The Big Bang happened *everywhere* in space.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edited my question with new questions after your answer. Could you please check it?

Comment: It is considered better form to post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The Big Bang happened in every point of the whole volume of the Universe. We don't have to calculate the point - it us everywhere. Every single point (your finger tip, your bathroom, center of Mars, center of Andromeda galaxy, everywhere) experienced the inferno of the birth of the Universe.