# If nothing can travel faster than the speed of light, how can there be parts of the universe we can't see?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, faster-than-light

Assuming we originated from a single infinitely dense point in space time in the big bang, how can there be parts of the universe that we can't see as the light has not reached us yet, if nothing can travel faster than the speed of light relative to our frame of reference? Is that because the universe can expand faster than the speed of light? Or am I missing something?

Comment: We didn't originate from a single infinitely dense point in space time in the Big Bang. This is a common misconception. Search this forum for *flrw metric* for many, many related questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can space expand with unlimited speed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/)

Comment: @JohnRennie can you elaborate. That does not really answer the question, although it provides useful additional information.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to [Whats left at the center of the Universe after Big bang?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88208/whats-left-at-the-center-of-the-universe-after-big-bang) for some background info.

Comment: @Simon I think what John is trying to point you towards is that the Big Bang is not a location, it is a time. It did not happen in some place and then the universe expanded out from there, instead it is something that happened everywhere at a certain time.  Because of this, things did not have to travel away from us (so they did not have to go faster than light), they simply are not where we are and never were.