# How is it possible for you to be at the centre of the universe wherever you are?

Tags: general-relativity, universe, observable-universe

I saw on Richard Hammond Builds A Universe on BBC2 a few days ago that you are always at the center of the universe wherever you are.

Surely this is illogical, because you could never get to the edge of the universe.

If I am in the center, then what about that object 10 meters away. Is that at the centre too? How is this possible?

What if I am driving for example. Does this mean that I am moving the universe while I stay still?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the terrible tagging, I have no idea what this comes under!

Comment: To use a terrible analogy: *where is the center of the **surface** of a basketball*?

Comment: Believing anything you see on TV is almost as bad as believing anything you see on {Internet minus StackExchange} .

Comment: Sorry, but aren't we inside the universe? I don't get this relativity stuff!! :(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft But it was on the BBC, so its probably going to have higher credibility. I've also edited my question to show what I was watching when I saw this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the universe have a center?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/does-the-universe-have-a-center) and [Is there a center of the Universe if the Universe is finite?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91162/is-there-a-center-of-the-universe-if-the-universe-is-finite)

Comment: But when I say center, I do not mean the center of expansion. I mean like an object (say me!) at the center. Or is this the same thing?

Comment: @GeorgeH - apparently it's expanding from everywhere.

Comment: Wow - thats a great excuse to forget the diet! :D On a more serious note, what would happen at the edge - would you never reach it?

Comment: @KyleKanos Where the inflation valve is, of course :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Touche.

Comment: @GeorgeH: there is no evidence that the universe has an edge.

Comment: Oh - Really!?!?! I never knew that - I always thought it did...

Answer (score 0):

Let's define a 'centre' of the universe as a special point in the universe about where all space is expanding. If you go outside and make some [clever measurements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space#Understanding_the_expansion_of_Universe), you will find that the universe is expanding about every point in space... which means that all points in space are a 'centre' of the universe.

There's not really anything special about the universe expanding about every point in space- consider the ['raisin bread analogy'](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/hubble.html).