# A way to determine the exact location of the Big Bang?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

See [What is our location relative to the Big Bang?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2378/), which contains the following:

> *The conclusion is that the Big Bang happened everywhere, all at once.* Phys.SE users Ali and WernerCD reached this same conclusion.

Known:

The most distant galaxies seem to be traveling at faster than the speed of light, but Einstein said nothing can travel faster than the speed of light.

Question:

Do any galaxies travel at exactly the speed of light?  If so, it should be possible to determine the exact location of the Big Bang.

Comment: http://preposterousuniverse.com/writings/cosmologyprimer/faq.html#ftl

Answer (score 1):

There is a three dimensional shell of galaxies (none currently observed) that have a gravitational redshift relative to us that is consistent with a relative motion at the speed of light.  If you moved to any other galaxy in the universe, there is a very high probability that they would observe a different such bubble.

If you look sufficiently far into the past in ANY DIRECTION, you will eventually "see" the big bang.  The big bang happened everywhere, simultaneously.  It's not a place exploding, it is literally a time when it is impossible to run time any further backward.

Answer (score 0):

Since the super dense object that created the "big bang" created space and time, technically speaking, the "big bang" happened everywhere, as the amount of space the object took up expanded to be space as we know it now.