# What determines the end of space (universe)?

Tags: cosmology, universe

What determines the end of our universe?
Is it defined by the farthest out physical object or is it defined by the farthest out form of energy like light?

Comment: Why would someone downvote this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31127/2451

Comment: Are you talking about the *size* of the universe or the *fate* of the universe? The body of the question suggests the former whereas the title and Crazy Buddy's answer suggests the latter.

Comment: @MichaelBrown: Yeah Michael. I got confused by that sentence. So, I answered based on title *only* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe) article is good for the subject. It is determined only by the expansion of universe as far as we know. We can still think of the fact that, "If the universe had a beginning (like the Big Bang), then it should definitely have an end"...

For now, the universe is expanding and expanding. It is not defined by light nor a farther object. But instead, a spread-out hypothetical energy called dark energy. The interaction of this energy with gravity causes the [acceleration of universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_universe). From 2011, we can slightly incline over the expectation of a [Big Rip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_rip).