# Infinite Space && Infinite Energy?

Tags: energy, space

If space is infinite, is it also possible that energy is infinite?

Given that we can't really conceptualize infinite space, could we say with certainty that energy is not infinite? If so, how?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me. Energy of what? Can you try to be more clear. Otherwise, I fear it will be closed shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable question. Here are some more about the same thing [Is space unending?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31127/37364), [Size of the Observable Universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57402/37364), [How can a quasar be 29 billion light-years away from Earth if Big Bang happened only 13.8 billion years ago?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12049/37364)

We don't know how big the universe is. We can't see all of it. The Big Bang happened 13.7 billion years ago. That means light has been traveling for 13.7 billion years, and light can only get so far in that time.

The universe has been expanding. If light just now reaches us after having left something 13.7 billion years ago, we estimate that thing is 46 billion light years away now. Nothing travels faster than light, so we have no way of knowing what is farther away than that.

If space is infinite, and if on the average space has a certain amount of energy, it is reasonable to think that there must be infinite energy. Things are not that simple. But still, if the universe is infinite, it might well have infinite energy. But all we can say is that space is really big, and so is the energy in it.

Comment: Apparently we're alone in understanding the intrigue and mystery of this question

Comment: I am sorry you had a bad experience here. The question doesn't really fit this site in ways that are not your fault. It wasn't asked in a way that most users of the site are comfortable with. I think you may be right.