# Do we have proof that the universe is finite?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

I was just wondering if we have any proof at all whether the universe is finite or not. I have heard that it is indeed expanding - which could mean that it is possibly finite... is this true? or what is anyone's opinion?

Comment: I think we talk about matter distribution when we talk about the size of the universe and energy apart from space-time energy. We know about the expansion of that matter and energy, but the space probably has existed outside of our "universe". It's just that space is being created between the matter that is increasing the size of the universe.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24017/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25271/2451 and links therein.

Comment: No evidence either way. Genuine infinities, in my view, tend to be mathematical constructs rather than physical reality - which is debatable, and anyway would just be a hint/suggestion about this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Our universe is at least 93 billion light-years across, and still expanding. Since we are inside of it it is likely impossible for us to prove it is finite even if it is. On the other hand, the continuing expansion doesn't seem to be stopping anytime soon, which speaks to a possibly infinite universe.