# Question: Is our Universe finite?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

Is it at all possible to compare our three-dimensional space with the two-dimensional surface of an expanding ball where recombination-induced radiation from the point at the top of the ball travels geodetic paths identical to the meridians so that it eventually converges at the lower point of the ball? Thus, to the observer existing in the lower point, this radiation is visible as if it is coming from all directions, as is the case with our microwave background radiation, and in that case every point gets a picture of recombination only from its antipode. This would make the universe finite, not infinite ... (?)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24017/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9419/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The reference in the previous comment is quite old (2012),although there are more recent comments added.

Comment: Hi Kresimir: You may find the thread below helpful. You might also find its controversy of interest. https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/calculating-the-probability-that-the-universe-is-finite.1011826/