# Infinite Universe and Big Bang

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

A common view now in the physics community is that the Universe is infinite in extent (which makes Hubble sphere an infinitely small part of the Universe).
On the other hand, there is the Big Bang theory which states that the Universe began about 14 billion years ago.
So, how can the Universe be both infinite and have a beginning?  Or does the Big Bang only apply to the Hubble sphere?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136831/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1915/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution arises during the [inflationary epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflationary_epoch). It is hypothesised that some sort of phase transition during the first moments of the universe drove a tremendous expansion/inflation of space by many, many orders of magnitude. A few details are in the link. I'm not sure that an "infinite" universe is the prevailing view; just very much larger than the observable universe.

The thing is that this faster-than-light, exponential expansion of space effectively isolates different parts of the original universe meaning that our little patch is just part of a much greater whole. It simultaneously explains why the universe is "flat", and highly isotropic and homogeneous, and most importantly for this question, addresses the "horizon problem".

The first section of the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#Space_expands) on the exponentially growing scale factor during the inflationary epoch would be useful reading.

Comment: So then you are saying that the Universe in fact does have a curve?  Because if it is completely flat AND finite, that would imply an edge.  Which would be weird and violate the assumption that there are no "special" places in the Universe.

Comment: @David It's "flat" (in the sense of spacetime curvature) to about 1%. The 2d analogy is to imagine a grid on the surface of a ballon. If you massively inflate the balloon, the grid square you live in looks flat to you. But there is no edge.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe

"Many textbooks erroneously state that a flat universe implies an infinite universe; however, the correct statement is that a flat universe that is also simply connected implies an infinite universe. For example, Euclidean space is flat, simply connected and infinite, but the torus is flat, multiply connected, finite and compact."

Comment: @David What's your point? We don't know that we live in an *exactly* flat universe. The sentence from wikipedia simply means that even if we did you could not say that the universe was infinite.

Comment: I think I was just answering my own question :)
But your response is the best I got it.  Response accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If the Universe is infinite, then it had instantly grew from zero to infinity at the moment of Big Bang.

Note, that this is a possible model from General Relativity (GR).

But most probably GR is not applicable at the moment of Big Bang, because it contains singularity.

Comment: Hasn't the universe [always been infinite](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/how-can-something-finite-become-infinite) in extent? Even when all the stuff in it was in the same place?

Comment: I don't think it's true, Dims.  What you said violates the basic tenets of Big Bang and Inflationary theories.  Namely that after the Big Bang but before the inflation, the universe was microscopic.  Right after the inflation it became visible to the naked eye, but still smaller than a basketball.

Comment: The Universe could be microscopic, if it was finite. But FLRW metric tells it can be both finite or infinite. Observations tell it is most probably infinite, hence it never was microscopic. But any length unit, like 1 megaparsec, if propagated back it time, was microscopic.

Answer (score -1):

Infinity also pertains to time not just gravity. Time just didn’t start 14 billion years ago what was before that negative time?  and you haven’t mentioned dark matter which is supposed to make up 75% of all matter in the known universe. Gravity as you say should be slowing down the rate of expansion eventually collapsing the universe when In fact the universe is expanding at an increasing rate possibly caused buy dark matter ?

More that one Big Bang is probable in an infinite number of universes. 
There was an infinite amount of time before you were born and an infinite amount of time after you die 
And what is time ? no more than a measurement between two points

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Unfortunately, this is an "old" question and posting your answer brings it back to the front page. Therefore, please only post answers to old questions, if your contribution is significant. From my perspective your answer has many issues and does not qualify as significant.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, the universe is not infinite. There is enough reason to disprove an infinite universe model. In such a case, the universe can have a beginning. Reasons to why the universe simply cannot be infinite are as old as the time of Isaac Newton. The problem is gravity. In an infinite universe, the total gravity of the mass it contains would be infinite and the whole universe would collapse into a space of infinite density, a black hole. 
On the case of expansion, modern theories such as of inflation, accurately describe certain features what we observe, such as the CMBR (Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation).

Comment: This is wrong. The force of gravity would *not* be infinite, because gravity gets weaker over distance. (I also would not recommend using Newtonian gravity to model the universe.) Furthermore, measurements (e.g. from WMAP) support the theory of an infinite (or at least very large) universe.