# If the universe is 13,7 billion years old how it could be infinitely large?

Tags: cosmology, time, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

If the universe is 13,7 billion years old how it could be infinitely large? Maybe it is curved to account for being finite? But then there should be more spatial dimensions...is it right?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166405/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The possibily that the entire universe or multiverse had any beginning short of "past eternity" is very controversial:  In many cosmological models other than field-based inflation (whose "measure problem" has had no resolution after several decades), our Big Bang is considered to be "local", even though it has affected all of our currently-observable region.