# Does the Big Bang imply a finite quantity of matter in the universe, and that the universe is spatially finite (if boundaryless)?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, big-bang, observable-universe

If all matter was created in the Big Bang (not counting spontaneous generation of particle-antiparticle pairs), wouldn't that imply that a finite (if very large) amount of matter exists in the Universe?

By the same token, wouldn't that imply that the Universe is spatially "finite", i.e. a compact (if boundaryless) 3D manifold?

If not, why not?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9419/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1915/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Have you read about Friedmann universes with $k=0$ and $k=-1$?

Comment: @G.Smith I mean, writing down equations is one thing, but being physically possible is another, and I have a sneaking suspicion that solutions of those equations with $k = 0, -1$ might be unphysical to begin with.

Comment: Mainstream physics does not consider these models to be unphysical.

Answer (score 1):

All we really know is that all of the matter in the observable universe was a very uniform, very hot, expanding plasma about 13.7 billion years ago. We don't know where that came from. "Big bang" is just a name for our ignorance.

Whatever process produced that state could plausibly have produced a region of finite or infinite size. Whether it's finite or infinite, it could be just one part of a larger universe. At this point we just don't know.

Comment: I very much like this answer. @benrg